# Generic for TypeVar and Iterator (or another generic) of that TypeVar

Tags: python, python-typing

How to create a generic class for bounded TypeVar and Iterator of that TypeVar?

Like this:

```py
Model = TypeVar('Model', bound=MODELS_BASE_CLASS)
RecordReaderType = TypeVar('RecordReaderType', Model, Iterator[Model])


class RecordReader(Generic[RecordReaderType]):
    def func(self) -> RecordReaderType:
        pass
```

mypy throws an error: Type variable Model is unbound.

Update about MODELS_BASE_CLASS: it's an imported class, thats widely used as base for project classes. Like this:

```py
from lib import BaseClass


class FirstSubClass(BaseClass):
    pass


class SecondSubClass(BaseClass):
    pass

Model = TypeVar('Model', bound=BaseClass)
```

Comment: can you define MODELS_BASE_CLASS?

Comment: it's already defined in third party lib, and widely used in bases of project classes

Comment: So ``MODELS_BASE_CLASS`` is ``lib.BaseClass``?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the code shown. MyPy complains ``error: Invalid type "so_testbed.Model"`` for the definition of ``RecordReaderType``. PyCharm complains ``Constraints cannot be parameterised by type variables``. Keep in mind that a ``TypeVar`` is supposed to be filled with a type - the way ``RecordReaderType`` is defined gives no way to fill in the exact ``Model``.

Comment: MyPy currently does not support what you are doing here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/479 https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2756