# Type variable ... is unbound

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I have a base class `BaseTemplateData` which inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel`. Then, I want to have a property of the `BaseTemplate` class which stores a type of a child class of `BaseTemplateData`.
I'm doing the following, but I'm getting a mypy error saying `Type variable "file.path.TemplateDataType" is unbound`, when I'm explicitly passing a `bound` parameter to the `TypeVar` call.

I also would like to have another class `BaseTemplate2` which property doesn't store the type itself, but an instance of a child class of `BaseTemplateData`. Would the approach be correct?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel


class BaseTemplateData(BaseModel):
    """
    Base class for all templates.
    """


TemplateDataType = TypeVar("TemplateDataType", bound=BaseTemplateData)


class BaseTemplate(BaseModel):
    """
    Template class for email templates
    """

    data_model: Type[TemplateDataType]


class BaseTemplate2(BaseModel):
    """
    Template class for email templates 2
    """

    data_model: TemplateDataType
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate [question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270898/generic-for-typevar-and-iterator-or-another-generic-of-that-typevar#comment101041479_57270898)

Comment: @edd That question isn't the same since the problem there is that the second TypeVar is being bounded by another TypeVar. In my case, I'm bounding it with a regular class, which should work.

Comment: Why are your templates inheriting directly from `BaseModel` instead of the documented base class `BaseTemplateData`?

Comment: They are different. Templates are pydantic models which have a property called data_model, which in case 1 should be a type of a child of BaseTemplateData, and in case 2, it should be an instance of a child of BaseTemplateData.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with pythons `Typing` and can't imagine what you trying to solve by this code. But I don't understand why you need `TemplateDataType`?

Your expectations are:

> I want to have a property of the BaseTemplate class which stores a type of a child class of BaseTemplateData

> I also would like to have another class BaseTemplate2 which property doesn't store the type itself, but an instance of a child class of BaseTemplateData

Okay:

```py
from typing import Type

from pydantic import BaseModel


class BaseTemplateData(BaseModel):
    """
    Base class for all templates.
    """


class ChildBaseTemplateData(BaseTemplateData):
    """
    Child class for Base class.
    """


class BaseTemplate(BaseModel):
    """
    Template class for email templates
    """

    data_model: Type[BaseTemplateData]


class BaseTemplate2(BaseModel):
    """
    Template class for email templates 2
    """

    data_model: BaseTemplateData


a = BaseTemplate()
# it is okay. Because a.data_model is a "type of a child class of BaseTemplateData"
a.data_model = ChildBaseTemplateData

b = BaseTemplate2()
# it is okay too. Because b.data_model is "an instance of a child class of BaseTemplateData"
b.data_model = ChildBaseTemplateData()

c = BaseTemplate2()
# error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "BaseTemplateData") 
c.data_model = "string"
```

Here is a good explanation about [`TypeVar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933946/difference-between-typevart-a-b-and-typevart-bound-uniona-b)

Also `TypeVar` is using with [Generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html).

Here is no `Generics` in your example

Proper usage of `TypeVar` will be something like:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Generic

A = TypeVar("A", int, str)

class B(Generic[A]):
  pass

# Ok
a = B[int]

# Error: error: Value of type variable "A" of "B" cannot be "float"
b = B[float]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll try and let you know, but this seems to make sense. My idea with TypeVar was to explicitly make a Type which demands a subclass of BaseTemplateData, but all subclasses of BaseTemplateData have BaseTamplateData type so it makes sense.