# In Python typing is there a way to specify combinations of allowed generic types that are dependent?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a pretty small but versatile (maybe too much) class in Python that effectively has two generic types that are constrained together. My code (yet poorly typed) code should show my intent:

```py
class ApplyTo:
    def __init__(
        self,
        *transforms: Callable[..., Any],
        to: Any | Sequence[Any],
        dispatch: Literal['separate', 'joint'] = 'separate',
    ):
        self._transform = TransformsPipeline(*transforms)
        self._to = to if isinstance(to, Sequence) else [to]
        self._dispatch = dispatch

    def __call__(self, data: MutableSequence | MutableMapping):
        if self._dispatch == 'separate':
            for key in self._to:
                data[key] = self._transform(data[key])
            return data

        if self._dispatch == 'joint':
            args = [data[key] for key in self._to]
            transformed = self._transform(*args)
            for output, key in zip(transformed, self._to):
                data[key] = output
            return data

        assert False
```

I have double checked that this works in runtime and is pretty straightforward, but the typing is really horrendous.

So the idea is that when we set up `to` to be an `int`, then `data` should be `MutableSequence | MutableMapping[int, Any]`; when `to` is `Hashable`, then `data` should be `MutableMapping[Hashable or whatever type of to is, Any]`. I know that `int` is `Hashable` which doesn't make this easier.

My very poor attempt at typing this looks like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Hashable | int)
C = TypeVar('C', bound=MutableMapping[T, Any] | MutableSequence)


class ApplyTo(Generic[C, T]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *transforms: Callable[..., Any],
        to: T | Sequence[T],
        dispatch: Literal['separate', 'joint'] = 'separate',
    ):
        self._transform = TransformsPipeline(*transforms)
        self._to = to if isinstance(to, Sequence) else [to]
        self._dispatch = dispatch

    def __call__(self, data: C):
        if self._dispatch == 'separate':
            for key in self._to:
                data[key] = self._transform(input[key])
            return input

        if self._dispatch == 'joint':
            args = [data[key] for key in self._to]
            transformed = self._transform(*args)
            for output, key in zip(transformed, self._to):
                data[key] = output
            return data

        assert False
```

Which makes mypy complain (no surprise):

```
error: Type variable "task_driven_sr.transforms.generic.T" is unbound  [valid-type]
note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
```

Is there any way to type hint this correctly and somehow bound the type of `to` and `data` together? Maybe my approach is flawed and I have reached a dead end.

Edit: Fixed some code inside 'joint' branch of `dispatch`, it was not connected with the typing in question, nevertheless I have made it as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the union of `MutableMapping` and `MutableSequence` with a `Protocol`:

```py
import typing

DispatchType = typing.Literal['separate', 'joint']

# `P` must be declared with `contravariant=True`, otherwise it errors with
# 'Invariant type variable "P" used in protocol where contravariant one is expected'
K = typing.TypeVar('K', contravariant=True)
class Indexable(typing.Protocol[K]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: K):
        pass
    
    def __setitem__(self, key: K, value: typing.Any):
        pass

# Accepts only hashable types (including `int`s)
H = typing.TypeVar('H', bound=typing.Hashable)
class ApplyTo(typing.Generic[H]):
    _to: typing.Sequence[H]
    _dispatch: DispatchType
    _transform: typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]  # TODO Initialize `_transform`

    def __init__(self, to: typing.Sequence[H] | H, dispatch: DispatchType = 'separate') -> None:
        self._dispatch = dispatch
        self._to = to if isinstance(to, typing.Sequence) else [to]

    def __call__(self, data: Indexable[H]) -> typing.Any:
        if self._dispatch == 'separate':
            for key in self._to:
                data[key] = self._transform(data[key])
            return data

        if self._dispatch == 'joint':
            args = [data[key] for key in self._to]
            return self._transform(*args)

        assert False
```

Usage:

```
def main() -> None:
    r0 = ApplyTo(to=0)([1, 2, 3])
    # typechecks
    r0 = ApplyTo(to=0)({1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'})
    # typechecks

    r1 = ApplyTo(to='a')(['b', 'c', 'd'])
    # does not typecheck: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "Applier" has incompatible type "list[str]"; expected "Indexable[str]"
    r1 = ApplyTo(to='a')({'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}) 
    # typechecks
```

Comment: I can confirm this also correctly complains with something like: `r2 = ApplyTo(to=0)({"b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3})` (`Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "str": "int"; expected "int": "Any"`). I had hoped that this can be solved without `Protocol` but it seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2: my proposal below does not really answer the initial question, see the accepted answer for a more accurate solution.**

If I correctly understand, the line that makes mypy to cry is this one:

```py
C = TypeVar('C', bound=MutableMapping[T, Any] | MutableSequence)
```

There are some other topics dealing with a similar issue:
[Type variable ... is unbound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514342/type-variable-is-unbound?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can find further details on mypy doc here:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-type-aliases

Basically, mypy is telling you that it cannot bound a TypeVar with another one (remember that TypeVar are supposed to be used with Generic).

**Edit**: To be more precise, I think mypy needs `T` to be used inside a `Generic` context, to resolve its type hinting correctly (e.g. inside a `class A(Generic[T])`, so that it can "bind" `T` to the class' context).

I think the solution for your problem could be to use Generic Aliases instead.

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Literal, Generic, Hashable, MutableMapping, MutableSequence, Sequence, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Hashable | int)
C = MutableMapping[T, Any] | MutableSequence  # GenericAlias !


class ApplyTo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(to: T | Sequence[T]):
        self._to = to if isinstance(to, Sequence) else [to]

    def __call__(self, data: C):
        ...
```

And then, you can use ApplyTo like that: `ApplyTo[int](to=5)` or `ApplyTo[int](to=[5, 6, 7])`.

If I did not correctly understand your issue or if I am unclear, please tell me !

Comment: Your `C` is indeed a generic alias, but later you use it unparametrized as a parameter type. When you do so, is equivalent to `C[Any]` which is not you want - you probably wanted `C[T]` at least.

Comment: My attempt at solving the problem at hand made mypy complain about `C` at this specific line, but the root of the issue was much deeper. I think Enzo has solved the problem I had in mind.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I think you are both right, my proposition is not very useful, I will update it to point on the accepted answer. Thank you both !